# CSS rotation reset

Tags: css, transform, reset

i'm currently making a circular menu with icons that pop up when you hover your mouse over a certain area.

This part works well, however, things go wrong when i try to display a text in the center of that area when hovering over one of the said icons. The text is using the icon rotation and translation.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATgYR.jpg]

Here's the (relevant part of the) code:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="holder">
    <ul class="icons">
    <li class="icon1"><a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="./icons/block32.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class='tooltip'><span>This is a dummy text</span></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    .holder {
    position:relative; 
    margin:auto;
    float: left;
    }
    .holder a {
    position:absolute;
    }
    ul.icons {margin:100px; list-style:none; width:0px; height:50px; position:absolute;
    left: 8px;
    border:160px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px; 
    }
    .tooltip {
    display: none;  
    }
    ul.icons > li:hover .tooltip{
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: How about transform-origin?

Answer (score 0):

Use transform origin to move the origin of the element.

Example use will be:

```
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 6em;
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bMA28/2/)

[MDN has a great page on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)